3-way circuit with single pole switches
on there are multiple lights in my building's stair case controlled by two single pole motion sensor switches, one at the bottom and one at the top of the stairs. This is how the previous owner or electrician had them wired. I found the motion sensor switch online and it specifically says it's single pole and not suitable for 3-way applications. However, everything works well and the tenant tells me there have never been any issues. Is the wiring okay and I leave it as is or...? Thank you!


My father used to tell me, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Just to make it explicit what the answers here have already implied - this is NOT a 3-way situation.

The two sensors are simply in parallel
While connecting two manual switches in parallel to control lights doesn't usually produce a useful function (turning one switch on can't be undone from the other location), this isn't an issue for motion sensors as they turn themselves off automatically.  As a result, connecting motion sensors in parallel works fine, even for motion sensors that don't support a mechanical 3-way switch input.

If one wires two switches in parallel as shown, either switch will be able to turn on the light, but only the switch that turned on will be able to turn it off; if both switches have turned it on, both would need to be switched to turn it off.
Such an arrangement can make sense for switches which won't stay turned on, but instead switch themselves off after some duration; the light will stay on until all associated timers have elapsed.  It would make far less sense with conventional switches, and might violate some building code in cases where a room's lighting would be required to be controllable from multiple switches.  If the junction box is placed as shown, the wiring would be adaptable to use two conventional three-way switches if the white wire connected to each switch was taped to mark it as a switched hot, but neither switch's box would receive a neutral in that case.  I'm not sure if the grandfathering for switches without a neutral connection would apply in that case, if one could argue that the wiring was put in place to accommodate three-way switches before a neutral connection was required.
Unless building code recognizes remote-controlled or automatic switches as a concept, it would require that in-wall wiring accommodate conventional switches even in scenarios where remote-control devices might be able to satisfy code without them.  I can't say for certain whether this installation would satisfy code, but it seems reasonable for the task.
